# Selenium Extent Reporting Problem

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, test-report

I cannot figure out the problem. After the picture, another problem is here.  `htmlReporter.config()` is not working and I'm not able to fix it.

This is my dependency:

```java
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
 <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is HTML reporter config:

```java
htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("eBanking Test Project"); // Tile of report
htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Functional Test Automation Report"); // name of the report
htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP); //location of the chart
htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);]
```

And here is the code:
[image: Screenshot of the code and errors in IDE]

Comment: Apparently the library is not in your PATH. Can you confirm it?

Comment: the same code is running without any problem in aventstack version 3.1.2(which is previous version) but I am using latest  4.1.5 version and that problem occurs.

Comment: Was the ChartLocation class removed from on this major update?

Comment: HTML report is deprecated for java use spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Htmle report in extente report is deprecated from v4.1.3:

http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/v3-html-reporter.html

Use spark report instead,

http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/spark-reporter.html

The steps remain the same. Only the name changed and everything else works almost the same

Comment: thanks a lot. I followed your instruction and it works

Comment: @SmB please accept the answer

Comment: @SmB you can accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: I did it. I didn't know before, how to accept answer. thanks for helping